# Memory management advice - how to handle Zombies?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

In the below sample code, I am a bit lost as to why I am getting a NZombie on the line:

```
[Category getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];
```

I have looked through SO posts and other documentation but am new to objective-c and am spinning my wheels on this.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

//Copy database to the user's phone if needed.
[self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];

// Init the Array
activeCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
activeSubjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
quotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
quoteMaps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Initialize the Category array.
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.categories = tempArray;
[tempArray release];

//Once the db is copied, get the initial data to display on the screen.
[Category getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];


//populate active subjects and categories: 

activeCategories = [self getActiveCategories];
activeSubjects = [self getActiveSubjects];

// sort data

NSSortDescriptor *categorySorter;
NSSortDescriptor *subjectSorter;

categorySorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"category_title" ascending:YES];
subjectSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptorsCat = [NSArray arrayWithObject:categorySorter];
NSArray *sortDescriptorsSub = [NSArray arrayWithObject:subjectSorter];

[self.categories sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorsCat];
[self.subjects sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorsSub];

[categorySorter release];
[subjectSorter release];

// Configure and show the window
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

...

```
- (void)dealloc {

[activeSubjects release];
[activeCategories release];

[categories autorelease];
[subjects autorelease];
[quotes autorelease];
[quoteMaps autorelease];
[navigationController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Here is the getInitialDataToDisplay:

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

// Use this section to bring in database and populate the array
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];    
[database open];

QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


//appDelegate.categories = [appDelegate.categories sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

//POPULATE THE SUBJECT 
FMResultSet *result_subjects = [database executeQuery:@"select * from SUBJECT"];

while([result_subjects next]) {

    NSInteger primaryKey = [result_subjects intForColumn:@"SUBJECT_ID"];
    Subject *sub = [[Subject alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];

    sub.title = [result_subjects stringForColumn:@"SUBJECT"];
    sub.category_title = [result_subjects stringForColumn:@"CATEGORY"];
    sub.active = [result_subjects intForColumn:@"ACTIVE"];
    sub.isDirty = NO;

    [appDelegate.subjects addObject:sub];
    [sub release];

}

FMResultSet *result_categories = [database executeQuery:@"select distinct category from SUBJECT"];

while([result_categories next]) {

    Category *cat = [[Category alloc] init];

    cat.category_title = [result_categories stringForColumn:@"CATEGORY"];
    NSLog(@"loading category: %@", cat.category_title);

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    for (Subject *sb in appDelegate.subjects){

        if([cat.category_title isEqualToString:sb.category_title]){
            [cat.subjects addObject:sb];
            NSLog(@"   Adding subject: %@ cat.subjects.count=%i", sb.title, cat.subjects.count);

        }

    }

    [appDelegate.categories addObject:cat];
    [cat release];

}

//POPULATE THE QUOTES 
FMResultSet *result_quotes = [database executeQuery:@"select * from QUOTE"];

while([result_quotes next]) {

    Quote *sub = [Quote alloc];

    sub.quote_id = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"QUOTE_ID"];
    sub.quote_date = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"DATE"];
    sub.title = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"DESC1"];
    sub.desc2 = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"DESC2"];
    sub.excerpt = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"EXCERPT"];
    sub.note = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"NOTES"];
    sub.isDirty = NO;

    [appDelegate.quotes addObject:sub];
    [sub release];

}    


//POPULATE THE QUOTE_MAPS 
FMResultSet *result_quote_map = [database executeQuery:@"select * from QUOTE_MAP"];

while([result_quote_map next]) {

    QuoteMap *sub = [QuoteMap alloc];

    sub.quote_id = [result_quote_map stringForColumn:@"QUOTE_ID"];
    sub.quote_map_id = [result_quote_map stringForColumn:@"QUOTE_MAP_ID"];
    sub.subject_id = [result_quote_map stringForColumn:@"SUBJECT_ID"];
    sub.isDirty = NO;

    [appDelegate.quoteMaps addObject:sub];
    [sub release];

}    

[database close];

NSLog(@"Count of categories: %i", appDelegate.categories.count);
NSLog(@"Count of subjects: %i", appDelegate.subjects.count);
NSLog(@"Count of quotes: %i", appDelegate.quotes.count);
NSLog(@"Count of quoteMaps: %i", appDelegate.quoteMaps.count);

}
```

Here is the getDbPath:

```
- (NSString *) getDBPath {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"reference.db"];
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARC or not? Also, maybe you can show your Category getInitialDataToDisplay: class method.

Comment: and your [self getDBPath] method.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using [object **autorelease**] in your dealloc. Use [object release].

Comment: If, indeed, the error is coming from that line, it's almost certainly a problem in getInitialDataToDisplay or getDBPath, neither of which you provide.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I included these two methods in the above post now.  Let me know what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, the best thing to do is build->analyze ( cmd shift b ). This will point out your bug right away in almost all cases.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Nico, I like the looks of the Build + Analyze, but honestly I don't know what to do with the data.  Thats my problem - I am trying to learn who to properly manage the objects better and need some direction.

Comment: It will generate a blue tab, if you click on the tab it will point to the lines it thinks caused the problem.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

```
categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
.
.
//Initialize the Category array.
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.categories = tempArray;
[tempArray release];
```

u've setup categories, then setup the tempArray, replaced the one in categories with it thus making a leak, then released the temp arrayObject, which what categories is now also pointing on, so unless `"self.categories"` is a retained property it will be a zombie. there seems to be something wrong there.
I may need to see some more of your code (the property declarations and their synthesis to make sure.

is the Zombie called on "getInitialDataToDisplay" or on "getDBPath"
try dividing it on 2 lines to know pin point more

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not declare Category as retained property in .h file.If not, add following line in your .h file

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray Category;
```

And synthesize the property in .m as-

```
    @synthesize Category;
```

I think it will help ....